# How can I get the status?

Tags: c#, openvpn

Is there any possibility to get the status of the openvpn-gui, weather it is working or not?

I tried it with:

```
Process.GetProcessesByName("openvpn").Length
```

But this is always `0`, if there is no connection. I can click the `EXE`, then I got a red symbol and an entry in `taskmanager`, which shows `not connected`, but the process status in C# remains at `0`.

This is quite bad, because I can't kill this process and can't open a new one.
In my program I want to call a website, which is password protected, for this I need OpenVPN with its configurations. But I cannot start OpenVPN, if it is running, although it is not connected. So I want to check the status of this program, weather it is running or not.

1. How can I readout the status of the `EXE`?
2. How can I reconnect with C#, if there is no connection?

[I wrote a thread on openvpn forum (german) but they also do not know.](http://forum.openvpn.eu/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=9183)

Windows `netstat -r` or `ipconfig /all` or `/allcompartments` doesn't help.

I'm working with Visual C# 2010 Express and OpenVPN_2.3.2.0 on Win8.

PS: `ovpn-red.png`:

[image]

This is the status, I want to readout with C#.

Comment: Not sure what you want to do, but is `openvpn-gui.exe` kind of what you are trying to make?

Comment: I have to open openvpn to get a website with password block. I cannot -reconnect programmably and cannot reopen openvpn, if it is runnung.

Comment: You're probably looking for the [management interface](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/79-management-interface.html), but I think only one process is allowed to communicate with the openvpn.exe process at a time, and it runs elevated which both may be issues for using it.

Comment: Not this way. Ovpn & the C#-programm are both running on my computer. I want to check the status of ovpn with my C#-program. Switch it on/off/restart/reconnect. Starting it, if it isn't running - no poroblem. Calling a website if it is connected - okay. But if this ovpn is running **without** connection I C# cannot see this, allthoug it is listed in taskmanager. I want to know in which way you all are dealing with this.

Comment: I'm only interessted in getting the status of the **openvpn-gui.exe**. How can I get this, if it is not **connected** but started? Or: I want C# to "see" the "color" of the symbol in the launchbar. :-))

Comment: considering the program is called `openvpn-gui`, you should probably look for that name. You would only match `openvpn` if the connection was active